# mpirun within bash script yields different behavior

Tags: bash, mpi, intel-fortran

When I run

```
mpirun -np 2 exec
```

in the terminal, the exec runs in parallel. However, when I put the command within a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
mpirun -np 2 exec
```

I get the following thrown

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpirun: 96: .: Can't open /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpivars.sh
```

My guess is that the bash script is seeing a different set of environment variables, but I not sure how to confirm this guess.

Comment: which one is your script? `mpivars.sh` or `mpirun`, where did you put your script?

Comment: the second block is my script, the third is the output from the script. Script and original command (first block) are run from the same directory.

Comment: How did you run your script? from terminal or from cron? try `which mpirun` in terminal.

Comment: From terminal. `> which mpirun
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpirun`.

Comment: To confirm or refute your guess include the shell command `env` in your script; this should reel off the environment variables in the context the script is running in.  Are you sure that your interactive shell is BASH ?

Comment: `env` gives `SHELL=/bin/bash`. I'll compare the `diff` of the env output from the terminal and the script.

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same problem today, and found the solution here: 
[link to emuch](http://emuch.net/html/201311/6662143.html). 
According to this link, the intel compiler does not incorporate mpif90 and mpicc environment. If another mpi compiler is used, you need to specify the absolute directory of mpirun (which in my case is  /usr/bin/X11/mpirun). 
For example in my case, it's

```
/usr/bin/X11/mpirun -np 2 exc
```